# Jquery with IE7 : Object doesn't support property or method?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

I'm using Jquery 1.8.2 with IE7 (my clients need it T_T)
I created my own function like this

```
(function($)
{
    $.fn.suggestionBox = function(options)
    { 
       ............
       ...........
    };
})(jQuery);
```

And when I call it I get error : **Object doesn't support property or method 'suggestionBox'**

```
<script>    
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('input[name="myBox"]').suggestionBox({'ajaxUrl' : 'mySuggestions.do', 'targetInputBoxSelector' : 'input[name="myObjName"]'});


});
</script>
```

Anyways, it works on Chrome and IE8-9. 
Any ideas?

Comment: does it work in later IE versions if you set compatibility mode=IE7? (I normally hate compat mode, but Ie7 doesn't have any dev tools, so if it goes wrong in compat mode this might give you a change to use the IE8/9 dev tools to debug the problem. it's worth a try)

Comment: Yes, it works on IE8-9 as mentioned above.
I'm using IE9 and changing the browser mode to IE7 to test this and got that error above.

I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: (btw - avoid using compat mode for testing; it doesn't give an accurate picture of what a real copy of the old IE version would actually be like! In this case it's the only realistic way to get dev tools to help debug the problem, but in most cases you should avoid compat mode like the plague. To avoid embarrassment, make sure you use a *real* copy of IE7 and IE8 to confirm that it works in those browsers before giving it to your client)

Comment: The error you've reported is due to the suggestionBox script not loading or more likely not running. This presumably means it has an error in it. Do you get any errors in the console when the code loads? The most likely kind of error would be that you're using a DOM API that isn't implemented in IE7. Can't really say what that might be without the code though. Have you tried using the dev tools debugger to step through the code line by line?

Comment: Thanks for your recommendation, @Spudley.

I can't debug line by line since it doesn't even enter the suggestionBox function. It dies and throws error since the beginning call `$('input[name="myBox"]').suggestionBox(...)`. Anyways, I'll try again and will let you know.

Comment: Well that definitely points to a fatal syntax error in the suggestionBox code somewhere. I can't really help much more than that without seeing the code, other than to suggest checking for the obvious IE 'gotchas' like a trailing comma at the end of an array or object definition. Try adding `'use strict';` to the code to force all browsers to validate it in strict mode. Also, try running the script through JSHint and see it throws up any errors or warnings. Other than that, we'd need to see the code, or it's all guesswork from here on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found that the issue is from having excessive comma on the last element in array.
While modern browsers can ignore it, IE7 doesn't.

```
{A,B,C,}
```

Changing it to {A,B,C} fix this problem.